# Сортировка одного столбца в VBA

Tags: сортировка, vba

В документе есть всего 1 столбец по которому мне нужно выполнить сортировку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь ее выполнить следующим образом, но мне выскакивает ошибка:

```
NewWorkbook.Worksheets(2).[A:A].Sort Key1:=[A1], Order1:=xlAscending
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я не так указываю, и как отсортировать это единственный столбец? Эту сортировку я использую в другом макросе и она работает:

```
NewWorkbook.Worksheets(1).[A:M].Sort Key1:=[M2], Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: В таком варианте сортировку нужно выполнять на активном листе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Макрорекордер даёт следующее:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A:A")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Дальше можете рихтовать под себя...

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub sort_()
Dim sht As Worksheet, rRng As Range
Dim lRw As Long
    Set sht = Worksheets(2)

    With sht
        lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
        Set rRng = .Range("A1:A" & lRw)

        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=rRng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
            .SetRange rRng: .Apply
        End With
    End With

    Set sht = Nothing: Set rRng = Nothing
End Sub
```